# ASP.NET Core 3.1 docker image COPY failed on git actions

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, github-actions

I am using Github actions to build docker images, in local environment, the command to build docker works correctly, when using git actions I get the error

> COPY failed: no source files were specified

Action:

```
jobs:
  build:

  env:
    CAMINHO_PROJETO_DOCKER: ./Project/Project.WEB/Dockerfile
  
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.301

    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build .. --file ${{ env.CAMINHO_PROJETO_DOCKER }} --tag project-web:latest
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Project.WEB/*.csproj", "Project.WEB/"]
COPY ["Project.WEB.Domain/*.csproj", "Project.WEB.Domain/"]

RUN dotnet restore "Project.WEB/Project.WEB.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Project.WEB"
RUN dotnet build "Project.WEB.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project.WEB.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.WEB.dll"]
```

Action console:

```
Step 5/18 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
3.1: Pulling from dotnet/sdk
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1
 ---> 18588de00fb4
Step 6/18 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Running in 328748ae7eb0
Removing intermediate container 328748ae7eb0
 ---> 77c0b2cdb1da
Step 7/18 : COPY ["Project.WEB/*.csproj", "Project.WEB/"]
COPY failed: no source files were specified
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: The error message indicates that there's no files matching `Project.WEB/*.csproj` in the build context on the host machine. One thing I notice is that you use `docker build ..`, i.e. your build context is the directory above the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

use docker-compose
in the visual studio right click on the project and add docker orchestration then use
docker-compose up command it will work